# Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName returns different pcnames

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed an intranet web application that gets the pc name of the client that visits the site, all pcs are in the same domain.

When I run the project from Visual Studio I get my pc name right but when I deploy it on a server which is in the same domain and visit the site, it does not return my pc name but a different pc name that I dont have a clue where it gets it from.

For example:

From Visual Studio: 
HNYUI.mysite.org

From Server: 
AEWD.mysite.org

Could anybody tell me what is happening, please?

Comment: As a test can u get the IP as well and see if it matches your IP?

Comment: Also give `Dns.Resolve()` a try. MS Considered it obsolete, but it seem to produce better results.

Comment: Some clues : Are you sure you are not passing through a proxy ? If the `ServerVariables[“REMOTE_ADDR”]` is empty, the `GetHostEntry` will return the localhost machine (your server).

Comment: As a test can u get the IP as well and see if it matches your IP? –  this does not match as the IP I get locally is 127.0.0.1

Comment: If the ServerVariables[“REMOTE_ADDR”] is empty, the GetHostEntry will return the localhost machine (your server)  Answer: This command does return an IP address, it is not the server IP becasue when I ask users to visit the site I get different IP addresses for each user but none of them get their right pc name

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your great ideas, they help me out to find the real problem. A few weeks ago we migrate our network domain and the server for this particular web application was still pointing to the old DNS.

Thank you very much for your help =)